# Guitar chords vs piano chords

Tags: theory

Why do the guitar chords in fake books not match up with the piano chords? When I play the song on piano, the corresponding guitar chord is different.

Comment: Is there a capo specified for the guitar part? Can you post an image of part of one of the scores you’re talking about?

Comment: How are they different? Do you have two different fake books or are both piano and guitar chords in the same book?  Do you mean the voicing are different? Playing a chord’s voicing from the piano may be either difficult and in a lot of cases impossible on the guitar.

Comment: Do you mean the actual chords, their voicings, are you looking at a Bb book?

Comment: Could you give us some examples? There are many possibilities...

Comment: You can help make this better by giving an example.  The fake book is... fake.  The chords work but that does not mean they are the original harmonies in the score.  There are many possible chord substitution possible that may be in use.  Also there are enharmonic chords (e.g. A-7 and C6 are identical notes different voicing).  It's possible that two versions don't seem to be the same but are functionally equivalent.